# Check how many items will be visible in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I can check how many items are visible but after they are showed using method `isViewPartiallyVisible`.
Is there possibility to check how many items will be visible (as whole item) in RecyclerView before they are showed ?

Comment: it depends on the height of the RecyclerView and the height of the Items

Comment: No, because the system can't know absolute size of your views before it draw (it depends on device screen).

Answer (score 0):

The top and bottom visible child depends on the LayoutManager. you can use

```
int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```